# find two numbers that add up to 8 and multiply to 20

Tags: complex-numbers

Find two numbers that add up to 8 and multiply to 20.
Only the complex number "i" (imaginary number) is allowed other than the real numbers. **But you do not necessarily have to use "i" if it is unnecessary. Just putting out the possibilities**

I've been doing trial and error for ages and I can't find any. Tried decimals, fractions, etc... What is a good way to go about solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the two numbers we want. Then $x + y = 8$ and $xy = 20$. Using the first equation, we have that $y = 8-x$. Plugging this into the second equation gives $x(8 - x) = -x^2 + 8x = 20$. Then we have $-x^2 + 8x - 20 = 0$. Using the quadratic formula we get $x = 4 \pm 2i$. Then $y = 4\mp 2i$. Specifically, $x$ and $y$ should be complex conjugates of each other.

Answer (score 4):

Hint :

$(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$

where $a+b=8$ and $ab=20$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ a,b, $ are roots of $\,(x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b) = x^2 -(a\!+\!b) x + ab.\,$ But $\, a+b = 8\ $ and $\, ab = 20\ $ so $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

$$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2 ab + b^2 = a^2 + 2 ab + b^2 -4 ab = (a+b)^2-4ab = 64-4*20 = -16$$

So $$a-b=4 i$$

Add the two
$$ a+b=8\\a-b=4i$$ to get
$$2a=8+4i \text { or } a = 4+2i$$
Subtract to get
$$2b = 8-49 \text { or } b = 4-2i$$